# ElasticSearch: Delete field from all documents where it exists (with Painless?)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

**Situation**: I have an index with strict mapping and I want to delete an old field from it which is no longer used. So I create a new index with mapping that doesn't include that field and I try to reindex the data into the new index.

**Problem**: When I reindex, I get an error, because I'm trying to index data into a field that is not available in the mapping. 
So to solve this, I want to remove that field from all documents in the original index first, before I can reindex.

```
PUT old_index/_doc/1
{
    "field_to_delete" : 5
}
PUT old_index/_doc/2
{
    "field_to_delete" : null
}
```

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  }
}
```

```
"reason": "mapping set to strict, dynamic introduction of [field_to_delete] within [new_index] is not allowed"
```

**1. Some places I found suggest doing:**

```
POST old_index/_doc/_update_by_query
{
  "script": "ctx._source.remove('field_to_delete')",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field_to_delete"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However that doesn't match documents that have an explicit value of `null`, so reindexing still fails after this update.

**2. Others (like members of the Elastic team in their official forum) suggest doing something like:**

```
POST old_index/_doc/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
          if (ctx._source.field_to_delete != null) {
            ctx._source.remove("field_to_delete");
          } else {
            ctx.op="noop";
          }
      """
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

However this has the same problem - it doesn't remove the second document that has an explicit value of `null`.

**3. In the end I could just do:**

```
POST old_index/_doc/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.remove("field_to_delete");"}
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

But this will update all documents and for a large index could mean additional downtime during deployment.

Answer (score 10):

Eventually I found the correct way to do it, so I'm sharing it for the general knowledge:

```
POST old_index/_doc/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
        if (ctx._source.containsKey("field_to_delete")) {
            ctx._source.remove("field_to_delete");
        } else {
          ctx.op="noop";
        }
      """
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using `containsKey`, good catch ;-) ES will still have to iterate over all the documents, but only those having `field_to_delete` will effectively be updated.

Comment: you should use an exists query instead of the match_all. Then your script will only be run on document with the field to delete. See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html

Comment: @PierreMallet: Unfortunately that wouldn't work, as the query would not return the document with `"field_to_delete" : null` and it won't be updated

Comment: Oh yes you are right :/ you could maybe work around this with an explicit null_value. See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html