# Always getting version conflicts issue when trying to remove fields from Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just trying to remove a field from all documents in my `Elasticsearch` index in `Kibana` on `AWS` and it is always giving me `version conflicts` error for all of the documents even though I am issuing just one request and sure that no one else is updating the index at the moment. I tried nearly all of the solutions from here but all of them lead to the same issue and no documents get updated:

[Remove a field from a Elasticsearch document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002215/remove-a-field-from-a-elasticsearch-document/39884267)

For instance:

```
POST /grch38_test__wes__grch38__variants__20210222/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.remove(\"AC\")"
  },
  "query" : {
      "exists": { "field": "AC" }
  }
}
```

Why is this happening? What could I try?

Exact message:

```
{
  "took" : 12768,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 11034,
  "updated" : 0,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 12,
  "version_conflicts" : 11034,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error msg?

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with the resulting output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve it using the solution found in the thread:

[ElasticSearch: Delete field from all documents where it exists (with Painless?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649273/elasticsearch-delete-field-from-all-documents-where-it-exists-with-painless)

Comment: can u atleast share the solution which worked for u?
i tried all possible solutions from link u mentioned but nothing working for me